# Triggering Events in ag grid for unit test

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs, ag-grid

i wanted to trigger ag grid events manually but don't know how

So I have a event tied to a column which is type of cell clicked event, and when you click on it, it opens a mat dialog.
So the question is how can you trigger that event for unit testing? I tried to get that cell with Dom and click on it, and also use the grid API but it doesn't work.

```
it('checking mat dialog option', async ()=>{
jest.spyOn(matDialog,'open');

//using grid api which doesn't work
// component.gridOptions.api.dispatchEvent(cellClikcedEvent);

// using dom
const select= fixture.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('.ag-cell');
select[3].dispatchEvent(new Event('click));
// or  select[3].click();

expect(matDialog.open).toBeCalled();
)
```

there are typos, i'm writing this question at home and don't have my code , but the logic is some thing like above. there is a really bad documentation about it too. like you don't know how you can use it

Answer (score 1):

I like to use `triggerEventHandler` for this on the `DebugElement`.

```
it('checking mat dialog option', () => {
  jest.spyOn(matDialog,'open');
  
  const cell = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('ag-grid'));
  // the first string argument is the event you would like to trigger, the second argument is the $event that you would like to mock
  cell.triggerEventHandler('cellClickedEvent', {});
  
  expect(matDialog.open).toBeCalled();
});
```

I am thinking, the DOM is something like this:

```
// HTML
<ag-grid
  (cellClickedEvent)="doSomething($event)"
></ag-grid>

// TypeScript
doSomething($event) {
  matDialog.open();
}
```

Learn more about `triggerEventHandler` here: https://netbasal.com/simulating-events-in-angular-unit-tests-5482618cd6c6.

Comment: thank you for your answer, i know about triggerevent handler but the problem is the event is inside grid options and inside the columndefs object and i don't know how to call that. take a look at this : https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/grid-events/

Comment: I would just do `component.gridOptions.onCellClicked({/* mock event here */})`

Comment: sorry for bothering you so much but it when i try to mock it, it says it's not a function and whitout it , it doesn't do anything

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure either. Can you show your `gridOptions` object?

Comment: this.gridOptions = {
      defaultColDef: { sortable: false, resizable: true },
      columnDefs: [
        {
          field: 'info',
          headerName: 'show info',
          onCellClicked: (ev: CellClickedEvent) => this.showInfo(ev)}]}

Comment: oh it worked, i should've called it on the columndefs array on the specific index. thanks alot man